# CakePHP Rendering Error

Tags: layout, view, cakephp-2.0, rendering, intermittent

I have a CakePHP 2.3.0 site I've been working on without issue until now.

On my local setup everything works.  On our original deployment everything works.  But now, on a new deployment (using the same hosting provider as the first deployment) I'm getting very strange behavior.

Occasionally, and I've been unable to pin it down to any particular controllers/actions, I will get the View rendered properly, but the layout that wraps it will not be included.  Basically, instead of getting a complete HTML document, I'm getting only the markup for the view.  There do not appear to be any errors in output in the view markup, so I'm not sure what/where the problem is occurring.

What is strange is that, once this condition has been triggered, all other controllers/views do the same thing, but waiting some amount of time (a few minutes; I've been unable to nail it down to a more specific period of time) seems to reset whatever the problem is and the complete layout(s) and view(s) render correctly again.

The guy here who manages our hosting tells me there are no apache logs and that it's a hassle getting the hosting provider to provide them, so I'm sort of stuck there.  Given that the breakdown seems to be occurring within Cake itself, I'm not really sure where to even start troubleshooting.

Has anyone else ever encountered this?  Anyone have suggestions on where to being debugging?  The lack of error logs is frustrating, but it's the situation I'm in.

Comment: sounds like caching. turn on debugging in Config/core and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: I have "Configure::write('debug', 2);" set and am seeing no messages, just incomplete output.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like some caching issue. if it's on cake's end, please try deleting your `app/tmp/cache` files.

Comment: I gave this a try but I'm still having the problem.